# ASP.NET MVC Validation - localisation of the error string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I followed the techique ASP.NET MVC 2: Model Validation from Scott Gu. (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

However I am building a localised web site.  How can I localized the error string?

I tried the following by replacing the following:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}",ErrorMessage="Must be a 4 digit year")]
public  Nullable<int> YearOfWork { get; set; }
```

With the following:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}",ErrorMessage=Resources.SharedStrings.search_error1)]
public  Nullable<int> YearOfWork { get; set; }
```

but I get a complilation error:

> An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an
>   attribute parameter type

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it so I am just posting it in case someone ever wants to know how it is done:

[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}", ErrorMessageResourceName= "search_error1", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.SharedStrings))]
        public  Nullable YearOfWork { get; set; }